# Openlayers WMS Issue

Tags: openlayers, wms

I try to load a WMS into my map, like so:

```
<html>
<head><title>OpenLayers WMS test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("maparea");
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("TIRIS", "https://gis.tirol.gv.at/arcgis/services/Service_Public/oph05_wms/MapServer/WMSServer",
            {format: 'image/jpeg', 
             bbox: '10.07,46,13.03,47.735',
             layers: 'Orthophoto_Tirol_05m', 
             width: 256, 
             height: 256},
            {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            units: "m",
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(10.07,46,13.03,47.735)});
map.addLayer(wms);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
alert("Request string: " + wms.getFullRequestString());
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>WMS Test</h1>
<div id="maparea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get no errors in the chrome console and thus don't know where to go from here..
If I open the links from the network tab (like: https://gis.tirol.gv.at/arcgis/services/Service_Public/oph05_wms/MapServer/WMSServer?FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&BBOX=11.55578125,46.864296875,11.558671875,46.8671875&LAYERS=Orthophoto_Tirol_05m&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326) I get a blank screen..

Here's a live example: http://gimoya.bplaced.net/WMS_test.html

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: The working example is username and password protected, which makes it hard to debug. If you could grab a working wms url from that via network tab, it would help (assuming you are allowed to).

Comment: @JohnBarça, sorry I put the html to an accessible directory on my ftp! For your second question: I thought what I posted from the network tab is what you are asking for, isnt it?

Comment: Normally you don't condigure things like BBOX, width and height in OpenLayers.Layer.WMS. The minimum is layer name, URL and `layers` (normally). See here: view-source:http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/lite.html.

Comment: Thanks - I got it! indeed, several parameters were not needed. The correct layer name was however crucial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I'll post the working code here (thanks to the commentators!):

```
<html>
<head><title>OpenLayers TIRIS layer=Image WMS test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
var options = {
    attribution: {
        title: "Provided by OSGeo",
        href: "http://www.osgeo.org/"
    }
};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("maparea");
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("TIRIS Orthofoto", "https://gis.tirol.gv.at/arcgis/services/Service_Public/oph05_wms/MapServer/WMSServer",
            {format: 'image/jpeg', 
             bbox: '1120600.9234869999345392,5879594.4111510002985597,1453307.4140270000789315,6067102.8815350001677871',
             layers: 'Image'},
            {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(1120600.9234869999345392,5879594.4111510002985597,1453307.4140270000789315,6067102.8815350001677871)}
            );

map.addLayer(wms);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
alert("Request string: " + wms.getFullRequestString());
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>WMS Test</h1>
<div id="maparea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```